# Is it possible to seed only with aria2?

Tags: bittorrent, seeding, torrent, aria2

I build a little tool (IoT) with an Intel Compute Stick which downloads a torrent content and then seed it.

And it works.

Now I want to seed the files I have downloaded EVEN after a restart and without re-downloading them (for obvious reasons...)

There is no way to do it with any option on aria2 ([here is the doc](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html)) and I want to know if there is a trick I can do or any other COMMAND LINE application that can do it ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks like you can do this with the -V option, although it does not look to be very well documented. From [this](https://nurtya.wordpress.com/2011/02/21/ubuntu-app-aria2-howto-use/) web page:

> You can seed downloaded file using -V option. This will first check piece hashes for the downloaded file.

```
aria2c -V -d/path/to/dir file.torrent
```

I'd suggest also adding `--seed-ratio=0.0` so that you'll seed the file forever:

```
aria2c -V --seed-ratio=0.0 -d/path/to/dir file.torrent
```

Answer (score 6):

I understand that it's an old question, but in case someone (like me) finds it -

The `-V` options works just fine, but if you do not want to verify all files before seeding you can instead use `--bt-seed-unverified`.
[Official documentation](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#cmdoption-bt-seed-unverified).

For example, consider the following folder structure:

- torrents data

  - .torrent files

To seed torrents you can use this command from directory with .torrent files: 
`ls | aria2c --bt-seed-unverified --seed-ratio=0.0 -d "../" -i -`